# Как применить preg_match для большой строки?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, apache

```
preg_match('/<div class="text_story_div"[^>]+>((?:.|\s)+)<\/div>/', $html, $find);
```

$html хранит хтмл код на ~4к строк - от него апачи падает. А если его сокртить до нескольких строк то все норм. Что делать?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, от чего именно падает апач и в чём это выражается. Но что делать - в любом случае ясно: раз и навсегда забыть про разбор HTML при помощи регулярных выражений.

Comment: @klopp, просто вылетает windowsовское окно что апач прекратил свою работу. поясните причину пожалуйста. и что делать тогда?

Comment: Если совсем коротко, то регекспы и HTML - это разные [типы грамматик](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%A5%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE). И не всякий HTML в принципе может быть корректно обработан регекспом, что, видимо, на этом конкретном фрагменте HTML происходит (или начинает отжираться память, или происходит зацикливание, или вечная рекурсия, etc). Что делать - пользоваться парсерами, начиная с [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), или какими-нибудь SAX-подобными...

Comment: Попробуйте так- это менее требовательно к памяти  

    preg_match('/<div class="text_story_div"[^>]++>((?>(?:[^<]++|<(?!\/div>))+))<\/div>/', $html, $find);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Апачу не хватило памяти или времени

```
((?:.|\s)+)
```

Расшифруйте, что вы сами понимаете под этим выражением? По-моему, должно быть так

```
/<div class="text_story_div"[^>]+>(.+?)<\/div>/
```

Это означает любой текст между `<div class="text_story_div" ...>` и первым попавшимся закрывающимся `</div>`, даже если он относится к совершенного другому открывающемуся.

Но я для разбора HTML не пользуюсь регулярками. Сначала я пропускаю текст через **[tidy](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.tidy.php)**, а затем с помощью **[DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php)** и **[XPath](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.domxpath.php)** получаю текст.

Если верстка сложная, то пользуюсь расширением **[phpQuery](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php)** и css-сетекторами.